# Datepicker : MultiDate doesn't work with maxDate and minDate

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to develop a date picker where we can select multiple random date between the minDate and maxDate but with minDate and maxDate, multidate is not working.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    minDate: -3,
    maxDate: 2
});

$('.date').datepicker('setDates', [new Date(2014, 2, 5), new Date(2014, 3, 5)])
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: could you show your html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minDate and maxDate dont exist in Bootstrap-datepicker but in another plugin jquery Datepicker,

so to use the same logic in bootstrap-datepicker, you have to use options startDate and endDate.

so `minDate:-3` becomes `startDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3))`

and `maxDate:2` becomes `endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 2))`

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    startDate: settingDate(-3),
    endDate: settingDate(+2)
});

/* if you want to change the start and end Date (MM,DD,YYYY)
  $('.date').datepicker('setStartDate', "04/14/2020");
  $('.date').datepicker('setEndDate', "05/10/2020");
*/


function settingDate(num){
  return new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + num))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a sample from the current date, but you could adapt following the date selected.

in this case you have to use methods: `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` (see [THAT](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate)) to set other limits to select date..